# How to change the default LookAndFeel for the entire application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, look-and-feel

[This page](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2412) lists a way to change the default LookandFeel for a .net application using DevExpress 10.2. It's not working for me.

My code (in `Main()`)

```
imports DevExpress.LookAndFeel

DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName = "Caramel"
DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.UseWindowsXPTheme = False
DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.LookAndFeelStyle.Office2003
```

My users hate this new grey theme and want Caramel back... suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work. But you have to make sure that all your forms are derived from DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm (for a Winforms-Application). Otherwise the LookAndFeel will not be propagated to the controls on the forms.
In general: if you place a devexpress control in a container that is not derived from a devexpress container the look-and-feel will not change.

Edit: the original question & answer was for DevExpress v 10.x. Starting with DevExpress V 2011.2 you need to reference a "DevExpress.BonusSkins.vXX.Y"-library in your project and register the bonus skins via

```
DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();
```

The bonus skin libraries are called e.g. "DevExpress.BonusSkins.v12.1.DLL" and can be found in the "\Bin\Framework"-Folder of your DevExpress-installation.

Complete code would look like:

```
DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();
DefaultLookAndFeel defaultLF = new DefaultLookAndFeel();
defaultLF.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = true;
```

Comment: All forms are derived from XtraForm 10.2. This is turning out to be a real head-scratcher!

Comment: The code i am using in my app is exactly this:
DefaultLookAndFeel defaultLF = new DefaultLookAndFeel();
defaultLF.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = true;
defaultLF.LookAndFeel.SkinName = "Caramel";
Maybe give this a try?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a project that uses any Developer Express component, a reference to the `DevExpress.Utils` library is added to it. This library contains helper classes common to all components and also provides some default skins

> (e.g. DevExpress Style, Metropolis, VS2010, Office 2010 Blue, etc.).

Other skins

> (Caramel, Coffee, Liquid Sky, Stardust, etc.)

are implemented in the DevExpress.BonusSkins library

To register skins shipped with the DevExpress.BonusSkins library, call the static Register method of the `DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins` class.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    // Skin registration. 
    DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

See [this link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3096) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work for you:

```
 DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName = "Caramel"
 DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.UseWindowsXPTheme = False
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have above, and it the default grey still loads in all forms. I'm putting it in main(). Can you elaborate? (I thought I followed your documentation...)

Comment: I think that this code is overriden somewhere.  Are you using the DefaultLookAndFeel control in your app?  Perhaps its settings override the code above.

Comment: I haven't explicitly changed it anywhere. I'm not using the control, but I can add it if it'll solve my problem :-p

Answer (score 1):

After i read much, i did like this and run me perfect!

1 - Create a module and write this code:

> ```
> Imports DevExpress.LookAndFeel
>
> Module Program
> <STAThread()> _
> Public Sub Main() 
>
>    DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register()
>    DevExpress.UserSkins.OfficeSkins.Register()
>
>    DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.UseWindowsXPTheme = False
>    DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = True
>    DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName = "Caramel" 'For Example!
>
>    DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableMdiFormSkins()
>    DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins()
>
>    Application.Run(New Form1)
>
> End Sub
>
> End Module
> ```

2 - And OBVIOUSLY Change this line in each form (Form1.Designer.vb):

> ```
> Partial Class Form1
>
> REM Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
>
> Inherits DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
>
> End Class
> ```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the LookAndFeelStyle to "Skin":

```
DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.LookAndFeelStyle.Skin
```